# Most efficient way to implement template-based optional class members in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, templates

I have a performance-critical application and need to modify the behavior of my class by various traits classes. Some of the more complex variations require additional class members in the main class.

So my question is: What is the most efficient way to provide such members depending on the traits class used?

What I would like to have is something like this:

```
template <class Traits> MainClass {

    typedef typename Traits::MemberType MT;

public:
    MT my_member;

    void do_something() {
        std::cout << Traits::get_number(this) << std::endl;
    }

    ...

};

class Zero {
public:
    typedef void MemberType;

    static inline int get_number(MainClass<Zero>*) { return 0; }
}

class IntegerNumber {
public:
    typedef int MemberType;

    static inline int get_number(MainClass<IntegerNumber>* myclass) { return myclass->my_member; }
}
```

Now this doesn't work, since you can't declare a variable void. But since I will have a large number of instances of MainClass and there are many different traits classes I don't want to have "dummy" variables for each possible trait.

One possibility to implement this would be by inheritance, but this is exactly what I want to avoid by using templates in the first place, since this can lead to the loss of performance, especially when having several different traits.

So my questions are:

1. Can I tell the compiler to eliminate certain unused member variables in a class?
2. How would you approach the problem? Are there other possibilities to implement this?
3. Which approach is the most efficient?

Comment: AFAIK you can only do this by specializing the template or using the preprocessor.

Comment: Will inheritance without polymorphism cause performance issues (I think it's optimized by the compiler and that it will not cause runtime overhead but I'm not sure) ?

Comment: @NathanOliver I would like to avoid the preprocessor if possible (It can't be bound directly to the templates anyway, right?). When talking about template specialization, are you referring to the solution proposed by Sopel or do you have something else in mind?

Comment: @nefas I thought so, but I am not so sure anymore. Probably with a small base class this will indeed be optimized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this example this should do, I don't know however it is enough for your needs.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class MemberType>
class MainClassBase
{
public:
    MemberType my_member;
};

template <>
class MainClassBase<void>
{
};

template <class Traits> 
class MainClass : public MainClassBase<typename Traits::MemberType> {

public:

    void do_something() {
        std::cout << Traits::get_number(this) << std::endl;
    }

};

class Zero {
public:
    typedef void MemberType;

    static inline int get_number(MainClass<Zero>*) { return 0; }
};

class IntegerNumber {
public:
    typedef int MemberType;

    static inline int get_number(MainClass<IntegerNumber>* myclass) { return myclass->my_member; }
};
class String {
public:
    typedef std::string MemberType;

    static inline std::string get_number(MainClass<String>* myclass) { return myclass->my_member; }
};

int main()
{
    MainClass<Zero> mainClassZero{};

    MainClass<IntegerNumber> mainClassInteger{};
    mainClassInteger.my_member = -1;

    MainClass<String> mainClassString{};
    mainClassString.my_member = "asd";

    mainClassZero.do_something();
    mainClassInteger.do_something();
    mainClassString.do_something();
}
```

Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/013aabb763149596

The empty base class must be optimized (in C++11 and higher) if your type is standard layout. If it's not, then it's still very probable it will be optimized.

Comment: This looks promising although (as far as I understand) there will still be some overhead due to inheritance when the class defines members. Will there be problems with multiple inheritance in the optimization process? (Since I will have several different traits with possible additional members)

Comment: If base class(es) are not virtual then it should get optimized. You can always check by looking at assembly output.

Comment: @cero non-virtual inheritance doesn't add overhead