# multiple optional members in class template without overhead

Tags: c++, templates, optional-parameters

If I want a class with an optional member, I'm using template specialization:

```c++
template<class T>
struct X {
  T t;
  void print() { cout << "t is " << t << '\n'; }
};
template<>
struct X<void> {
  void print() { cout << "without T\n"; }
};
```

This is nice as there is no runtime overhead and little code duplication.
However, if I have 3 instead of 1 optional class member, I have to write 2^3=8 classes, that is, the "little duplication" quickly becomes unreasonable.

A possible solution may be to use `std::conditional` like so:

```c++
template<class T1, class T2, class T3>
struct X {
  conditional_t<is_void_v<T1>, char, T1> t1;
  conditional_t<is_void_v<T2>, char, T2> t2;
  conditional_t<is_void_v<T3>, char, T3> t3;

  void print() {
    if constexpr (!is_void_v<T1>) cout << "t1 is " << t1 << '\n';
    if constexpr (!is_void_v<T2>) cout << "t2 is " << t2 << '\n';
    if constexpr (!is_void_v<T3>) cout << "t3 is " << t3 << '\n';
  }
};
```

but now, objects of my class waste memory. I'm looking for some way to avoid most of the code duplication (down to at most linear in the number of optional members code overhead) while avoiding to spend more runtime and memory than necessary.

Note that this question exists (with answers) for single optional class members (see [Optional class members without runtime overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65775033/optional-class-members-without-runtime-overhead), [Most efficient way to implement template-based optional class members in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309812/most-efficient-way-to-implement-template-based-optional-class-members-in-c)) but, to the best of my knowledge, it has not been answered for multiple optional members.

Comment: maybe you didnt know, if a user wants to see the history of your quesiton they can see it here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69222391/revisions. You need not add "Edit:..." or keep old contents

Comment: Is variadic template acceptable, or `t1`, `t2`, `t3` are really distinct meaning (i.e `<int, void, int>` and `<int, int, void>`).

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I chose to write "EDIT:..." instead of changing the question because now, people reading your comment are likely to incorrectly assume that it references the question in its current form.

Comment: they dont, because comment is removed ;) Consider that this happens frequently (comments refering to older revisions) and that comments are rather short lived, while what counts is what is in the question

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm not sure I understand the question. Yes, `<int, void, int>` should be a different class than `<int, int, void>` but, if I understand correctly, that is not in conflict with variadic templates.

Comment: Some pre-variadic template codes use tuple-like type with dummy type as `void` to simulate variadic, so to have `<int, int>`, they require to add extra `void`(generally defaulted) `<int, int, void, void, void>`. If it was your case, `template <class... Ts>struct X { std::tuple<Ts...> data; };` might be enough.

Comment: Have you thought about simply using a `tuple` instead of named members?  At least for that bundle of members; the main class would wrap their access to hide this detail.  The `tuple` can have different numbers of members, no problem.  It occurs to me that the elaborate efficient solutions posted are basically how `tuple` is implemented.

Comment: @JDługosz the problem would be that the index of an item `Q` in the tuple would depend on whether or not each optional member before `Q` is `void`. This would mean that (A) the `if constexpr` expressions will become enormous and (B) this cannot be generalized to an arbitrary number of optional members.
Other than that, I think you're right and I might end up using a modified implementation of `std::tuple`

Comment: @igel if the types were distinct, no problem.  I recall some tuple-like implementations allow for optional tags (which did not make it into the standard), so you might find a ready-made implementation already exists.

Comment: @JDługosz: And unfortunately, there are no required "optimization for EBO" for `std::tuple`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an optional_member class,

```
template <class T>
struct OptionalMember
{
    T t;
    static constexpr bool has_member = true;
};

template<> struct X<void>
{
    static constexpr bool has_member = false;
};
```

you might use inheritance (as long as their types differ) and EBO to avoid extra memory.

```
template<class T1, class T2, class T3>
struct X : OptionalMember<T1>, OptionalMember<T2>, OptionalMember<T3>
{
  void print() {
    if constexpr (!OptionalMember<T1>::has_member)
        cout << "t1 is " << OptionalMember<T1>::t << '\n';
    if constexpr (!OptionalMember<T2>::has_member)
        cout << "t2 is " << OptionalMember<T2>::t << '\n';
    if constexpr (!OptionalMember<T1>::has_member)
        cout << "t3 is " << OptionalMember<T3>::t << '\n';
  }
};
```

or, since C++20, attribute [`[[no_unique_address]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address) (no extra memory as long as their types differ).

```
template<class T1, class T2, class T3>
struct X {
  [[no_unique_address]] OptionalMember<T1> t1;
  [[no_unique_address]] OptionalMember<T2> t2;
  [[no_unique_address]] OptionalMember<T3> t3;

  void print() {
    if constexpr (!t1.has_member) cout << "t1 is " << t1.t << '\n';
    if constexpr (!t2.has_member) cout << "t2 is " << t2.t << '\n';
    if constexpr (!t3.has_member) cout << "t3 is " << t3.t << '\n';
  }
};
```

If type might be identical, you might modify `OptionalMember` to take extra tag (or any kind of identifier as `std::size_t`):

```
template <class T, class Tag>
struct OptionalMember
{
    T t;
    static constexpr bool has_member = true;
};

template<class Tag> struct X<void, Tag>
{
    static constexpr bool has_member = false;
};
```

and then

```
struct tag1;
struct tag2;
struct tag3;
```

and use `OptionalMember<TX, tagX>` instead of `OptionalMember<TX>` from above solution.

Comment: ah interesting, can we maybe replace the `class Tag` with a `size_t tag_num`? This should enable us to use variadic templates, thereby generalizing to an arbitrary number of optional members, right?

Comment: Yes, `std::size_t` is alternative.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use inheritance to only write 2*3=6 classes and separate the data from the actual code using it:

```c++
template<class T1> struct optional_tuple1 {T1 first;};
template<> struct optional_tuple1<void> {};

template<class T1, class T2> struct optional_tuple2: public optional_tuple1<T1> { T2 second;};
template<class T1> struct optional_tuple2<T1, void>: public optional_tuple1<T1> {};

template<class T1, class T2, class T3> struct optional_tuple3: public optional_tuple2<T1, T2> {T3 third;};
template<class T1, class T2> struct optional_tuple3<T1, T2, void>: public optional_tuple2<T1, T2> {};
```

However, you have to make sure that you're not using a variable `second` if `T2` is `void`. This can be achieved with `if constexpr (!std::is_void_v<T2>)` (as above):

```c++
template<class T1, class T2, class T3>
struct X3: public optional_tuple3<T1, T2, T3> {
  void print() {
    if constexpr (!is_void_v<T1>) cout << "first is " << this->first << '\n';
    if constexpr (!is_void_v<T2>) cout << "second is " << this->second << '\n';
    if constexpr (!is_void_v<T3>) cout << "third is " << this->third << '\n';
  }
};
```

NOTE: this is only optimal if not all `T`s are `void` since, if I recall correctly, classes cannot have size-0 in C++ (I'll assume because no 2 objects may receive the same address in memory).

Comment: You don't have twice the same base, so EBO might apply to all. even `<void, void, void>`  is fine.

Comment: right, if you use the `optional_tuple` by inheriting from it, but not if you have a member of type `optional_tuple` - I'm unfamiliar with [[no_unique_address]] tho, I have to read up on that...

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct member_haver {
    T m_member;
};

template<>
struct member_haver<void> {
};

template<typename... Ts>
struct X : member_haver<Ts>... {
    void print() {
        ((std::cout << member_haver<Ts>::m_member << ", "), ...);
    }
};
```

Then, for example, you could say:

```
int main() {
    X<int, void, float> x{};
    x.member_haver<int>::m_member = 1;
    x.member_haver<float>::m_member = 5.2f;

    x.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Of course this would probably need to be syntactically refined, but the gist is there.

Comment: You should add Tag, as `X<int, int>` is not possible currently.

Comment: Having a `static const bool has_member;` might be useful too.